# How to match first occurrence of a string with Regex?

Tags: regex

My regular expression matches the string in the last occurrence of VALUE. How do I tweak my RegEx to match the string only in the first occurrence after a certain string?

Regex: `NAME="var1".+VALUE="(.+)"`
Text:

```
<INPUT TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="var1" VALUE="value that i want to be captured"/><INPUT TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="var2" VALUE="value2"/><INPUT TYPE="SUBMIT" VALUE="value that is captured, but i don't want to be captured" />
```

My current RegEx captures the value: "value that is captured, but i don't want to be captured"

Comment: `NAME` and `VALUE` may appear in the reverse order in the input string. This is not a task for `regex`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/4265352

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> To answer your question

You need to make your regex lazy [`Regex quantifiers`](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html)

```
NAME="var1".+?VALUE="(.+?)"
```

[`Demo`](https://regex101.com/r/ZB14B0/1/)

Since this is HTML you must use some `HTML parser` for getting result, not sure which language you're working on but most of language do have HTML parse if not than there are libraries to help you with it